# EKEventEditViewController, prefill title and location

Tags: ios5, ekeventkit, ekevent

How to prefill title and location for created event in EKEventEditViewController?

Should I create EKEvent programmatically first, and then edit it? In this case how to delete it if user touched cancel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: create EKEvent programmatically first, and then edit it.

It works.

Answer (score 1):

When you have set the `eventStore` property into the `EKEventEditViewController`, it will have created its own event. You can edit that before you display the `EKEventEditViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Create the event first, then edit it.

```
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.startDate = lastSelectedDate; // your selected start date
event.endDate = [lastSelectedDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*2]; // your selected end date

// Creating event controller
EKEventEditViewController *eventViewController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
eventViewController.editViewDelegate = self;
eventViewController.eventStore = eventStore;

// Set event
eventViewController.event = event;

[self presentViewController:eventViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```